# Rails 5 routes and extensions

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have application where i send file through send_file in controller.
To authorize i use Pundit.

```
def avatar
  authorize @user
  send_file @user.avatar.path, disposition: :inline
end
```

In routes.rb I have

```
resources :users do
  get 'avatar', on: "member
end
```

in page source there is:

```
<img src="/admin/users/1/avatar" alt="Avatar" />
```

I'd like to change it to:

```
<img src="/admin/users/1/avatar.png" alt="Avatar" />
```

It works well, but how to add extension png. I convert all avatars to png file while signing up.

Regards
sssebaaa

Comment: If you just convert the image to png and store it in a folder that matches `/admin/users/:id/avatar.png` then you don't need a route in my opinion.

Comment: I want to hide avatars to other user and in def avatar i check permissions to avatar file. Without path like users\11\avatars i cannot check permissions. FIles are stored in hidden directory. If you ar not sign in you cacn display avvatar.

Comment: Well then having a predictable URL with the user's ID is probably not a good solution. Then I'd go with the route, check inside the action if the user may see to other user's avatar and then read the file from the file system and pass it through. Or send a placeholder.

Comment: Even you now user id you cant display avatar. I check permissions in def avatar   before send_file.

Comment: I know , that my solution works, but I'd love to looks it better. user/1/avatar.png looks better than user/1/avatar. To me of course.

Comment: I kinda get it, but honestly: why would you waste time on optimizing the beauty of a URL no user/customer is ever gonna see?